# How to avoid Child form button click event to call parent form handler

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile-6.5

I am working on windows mobile CE. I have the below question.

I have a parent form BookForm that displays book information in a table like book number, author etc. I have a button on the screen that says "Ok", that acts as back button.

I have child form PaidBookForm that display same data in same UI layout. I have a button btnSubmit on the screen that says "Buy", that takes user to another screen where user can buy the book.

```
public partial class PaidBookForm : BookForm 
{
}
```

I have event handler assigned to btnSubmit in parent form

```
this.btnSubmit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnBack_Click);
```

I have event handler assigned to btnSubmit in child form

```
this.btnSubmit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnBuy_Click);
```

The problem is:

`when Buy is clicked in child form, btnBack_Click is called first and btnBuy_Click is called. How do I avoid btnBack_Click to be called ?`

Comment: Is the same `btnSubmit` in both forms?  Or do you have a different button in each form that both have the same name?

Comment: Plese post more code. If you won't find any solution you may chceck the sender in the handler method and base behaviour on that altaugh it's ugly.

Comment: the button is same in both the forms. there are no separate UI controls in child form. The only difference in child form is page header, button text and button event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to keep in mind is that your "child form" *is also* your "parent form". They are not two different objects. The child form is an instance of the parent form, with additional functionality.

In this case, it seems that polymorphism might be the way to go. Instead of your current event handler subscriptions, do something like this:

```
class BookForm : Form
{
    protected virtual void SubscribeButton()
    {
        this.btnSubmit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnBack_Click);
    }

    public BookForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SubscribeButton();
    }
}

class PaidBookForm : Form
{
    protected override void SubscribeButton()
    {
        this.btnSubmit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnBuy_Click);
    }
}
```

If that is not appropriate to your needs, you really will need to post a good code example.

Comment: I tried this earlier with wrong syntax, so this did not work. But now this works partially. The issue is btnBuy_Click is getting called twice. Not sure why. I checked all the references of btnBuy_Click. I see only 2 references, assigning EventHandler and method definition

Comment: Perhaps you have neglected to remove the event configuration from the Designer properties? I.e. it's also being set in the InitializeComponent() method. Assuming you've ensure that's not the case, and that you aren't subscribing anywhere else, the above will subscribe the event exactly once, whether you are dealing with a BooKForm instance or a PaidBookForm instance. But you do have to double-check and make sure that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

Since `PaidBookForm` inherits from `BookForm`, it has all of the same code and event handling that its parent has.  This includes the event subscription that you defined in the base class.  So in your child form, there are 2 events that subscribe to `btnSubmit.Click` - `btnBack_Click` from the base class `BookForm`, and `btnBuy_Click` from the child class `PaidBookForm`.

There are a few ways to fix this.  One option would be to modify the child form code to unsubscribe from the base class event before wiring up the child class event, like this (SLOPPY CODING, NOT RECOMMENDED):

```
this.btnSubmit.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.btnBack_Click);
this.btnSubmit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnBuy_Click);
```

A better option would be to reevaluate your usage of inheritance.  It sounds like the two forms serve different purposes, but you're using inheritance because they have similar UI layout.  This violates the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (which is common when using inheritance for UI).

Instead, consider creating a `UserControl` that contains all of the common UI elements, and then adding that user control into your `BookForm` and `PaidBookForm` classes.  Then your two forms would share the same `BookInformationControl` (or whatever you call it) that has the common elements, but their event handling would be completely separated.

Comment: Is it good design to have a base form A that has data table to be displayed. BookForm and PaidBookForm will be derived child forms of A. BookForm will have its own button and PaidBookForm will have  its own buttons.

Comment: That would work as well, although I tend to limit UI inheritance since it makes composition difficult.  For instance, if the base form has all the controls on it, you can't move them on any child form if you need more room above or below.  But if you use a custom control, you can move it around or resize it as needed for each form that uses it.

Comment: Liskov substitution principle? lol never heard of that. Will read about that. Thanks for sharing.